# item text not going full length of tabularx column

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

I have this Latex code that produces the image below. How can I get the item text to span the whole column?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.4\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|s| b|}
    \textbf{\Large Hello} &  Text goes here
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Text goes here. Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here
        \item Text goes here. Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here Text goes here
    \end{itemize}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Because the second column contains a list-like environment, you must change its definition from `\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X}` to `\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=1.6\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}`. This is explained in greater detail in section 4.3, "Column widths", of the user guide of the `tabularx` package.